# Highcharts 3.0 combination chart not fully rendering pie (donut) chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highcharts 3.0 chart that shows both a column chart and a pie (donut) chart. This combo chart was rendering fine with the previous version of Highcharts.

Since upgrading the donut chart only renders to the highest y axis line and does not render above that line. The pie (donut) chart used to render completely with the top half of the pie (donut) chart being to the right of the chart title.

Any ideas?

[image: Highcharts donut chart]

I have added a jsfiddle with a small modification to the Highcharts provided combination chart (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo) to show the issue.

The only line I changed is where to center the pie chart.

```
center: [300, 1],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sh7wY/

Comment: Could you recreate your chart in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I added a jsfiddle example. Please see above.

Comment: I have reported that: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1659

Comment: Thank you. I had also reported it as https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1647

Answer (score 0, accepted):

highslide-software fixed the regression with pies being clipped to the plot area by default. They also provided a workaround which is working.

See https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1647.

Answer (score 0):

The pie chart is cutted, because is our of plotArea, where chart can be created. So you can modify pie size http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.size to make chart smaller or modify center parameter.

Comment: The pie chart used to appear just fine with Highcharts 2.x and I would like to continue to have the pie chart the same size and in the same position. This appears to be a Highcharts 3.0 issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this line :

```
center: [300, 1],
```

by this one

```
center: [300, 100],
```

The second parameter is equivalent to the style 'top' of your chart

Comment: I think center: [300, 50] is the best deal to you ;)

Comment: The pie chart used to appear just fine with Highcharts 2.x and I would like to continue to have the pie chart the same size and in the same position. This appears to be a Highcharts 3.0 issue.